# How do I filter posts by catogory?

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I'm developing a wordpress theme and want to display posts by a specific catagory named 'Artikel'. However, my code isn't working. This is my code:

```
<?php
    $custom_query = new WP_Query([
      'cat' => 'Artikel',
    ]);
    if ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
      while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
        $custom_query->the_post(); ?>


        /* do things */

        <?php

      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    ?>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: you are fetching data from wordpress default post type and category ?

Answer (score 0):

used category id not used category name

```
 $category_id=1;

    $custom_query = new WP_Query([
          'post_type' => 'post','posts_per_page' => -1,'order' => 'ASC','cat' => $category_id
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
                post_type => 'post',
                'category_name' => 'Artikel',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'ASC'
            );
    $custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
      while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
        $custom_query->the_post(); 

[etc.]
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Use this code to display the post from a specific category.

```
 <?php   $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' =>'4',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'name',    
            'terms'    => 'Artikel'
        ),
    ),
);   
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );  ?>
```